# How to detect and visualize ceiling with RealityKit?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Since RealityKit is new to me, apparently the plane anchors now have classification (floor, wall, ceiling, ...), so does anyone of you know the procedure of detecting ceilings (or any class of a plane)with RealityKit and ARKit and visualizing them using specific color (for instance red). Any information regarding this would be welcome.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/100290

Answer (score 0):

ARKit/RealityKit can detect horizontal surfaces, so yes, it can definitely detect a ceiling. Of course, ARKit won't inherently know that it is a ceiling vs a floor or a table. You could compare the ARPlaneAnchor's `y` value to the phone's present `y` value and determine that it is likely a ceiling and add geometry/coloration based on that.